# SQL unable to insert data into database

Tags: php, sql

My SQL code is not inserting in the table. Does someone know what i do wrong?

SQL/PHP Code:

```
$ownerid = $input->FilterText($_GET['ownerId']);
$widgetid = $input->FilterText($_GET['ratingId']);
$rate = $input->FilterText($_GET['givenRate']);
}

if(is_numeric($ownerid) && is_numeric($widgetid) && is_numeric($rate)){
    $myvote = $db->result($db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ".PREFIX."ratings WHERE raterid = '".$user->id."' AND userid = '".$ownerid."'"));
    if($myvote < 1 && $ownerid != $user->id && $rate > 0 && $rate < 6){
        $db->query("INSERT INTO cms_ratings (userid,rating,raterid) VALUES ('".$ownerid."','".$rate."','".$user->id."')");
    }
```

Hope someone can help me with this problem. Its not inserting @ database.

Comment: Any errors reported? Did you else after `if(is_numeric($ownerid) && is_numeric($widgetid) && is_numeric($rate)){` or echo'd inside it to confirm you are where you think you are?

Comment: I have no errors and its just not importing in the database. Something is wrong with the INSERT into i think... but i dont know what. Maybe you know? @chris85

Comment: try using msql_error() to show if its a syntax error

Comment: Are you sure you the `insert` query executes though? Have you diagnosed that already? If any of those variables have a `'` then it would fail.

Comment: what's inside the prefix?

Comment: Already tried that, no errors. Prefix = cms_ratings @HardSpocker

Comment: try taking the double qoutes: `$db->query("INSERT INTO cms_ratings (userid,rating,raterid) VALUES ('.$ownerid.','.$rate.','.$user->id.')");`

Comment: Now it says: Undefined variable: ownerid @HardSpocker

Comment: take the dots as well @ShredderReal

Comment: Which dots? @Hard Spocker

Comment: try taking the dots as well: `$db->query("INSERT INTO cms_ratings (userid,rating,raterid) VALUES ('$ownerid','$rate','$user->id')");`

Comment: Nope its still not inserting in my database @HardSpocker

Comment: @ShredderReal try this
$db->query("INSERT INTO cms_ratings (userid,rating,raterid) VALUES ('{$ownerid}','{$rate}','{$user->id}')");

Comment: Its does not work, still not inserting anything @MineshPatel

Comment: debug your query
echo "INSERT INTO cms_ratings (userid,rating,raterid) VALUES ('{$ownerid}','{$rate}','{$user->id}')";die; 
check output and run that query in  phpmyadmin

Comment: I have done it. He's echo (doing) nothing? I see no errors or something. @MineshPatel